# Issue with str_replace for scraped data

Tags: r, dplyr, str-replace

I'm trying to eliminate apostrophes from my a column of words in my dataset using

```
str_replace(tidy_posts$word, "'", "")
```

But the vector it returns still contains apostrophes. The vector's class is character, so I can't understand why this won't work. My only guess is that because  the words came from data I got from the reddit API, the encoding is funky or something.

edit: "[:punct:]" also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you are having some "special" punctuation such as `.` or `'` a way to select them in regex is by using `\\` before the punctuation of interest. This example may help you:

```
ch = c("The vector's class is character, so I can't understand why this won't work")

> stringr::str_replace_all(ch, "\\'","")

[1] "The vectors class is character, so I cant understand why this wont work"
```